# 'UIViewController' to 'WWCalendarTimeSelector.VNClockViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I get this error when trying to instantiate a viewcontroller from a storyboard.

I added a pod into my test project [WWCalendarTimeSelector](https://github.com/weilsonwonder/WWCalendarTimeSelector)
and edited the pod. I added new files `VNClockViewController.swift` and `VNClockViewController.storyboard`.

In my `VNClockViewController.swift`, I have this:

```
open static func instantiate() -> VNClockViewController {
  let podBundle = Bundle(for: VNClockViewController.self)
  let bundleURL = podBundle.url(forResource: "WWCalendarTimeSelectorStoryboardBundle", withExtension: "bundle")
  var bundle: Bundle?
  if let bundleURL = bundleURL {
    bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL)
  }
  return UIStoryboard(name: "VNClockViewController", bundle: bundle).instantiateInitialViewController() as! VNClockViewController //This line causes the error
}
```

but when I try to instantiate this `Viewcontroller` in my Project, I get the error

> > Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10326cca8) to 'WWCalendarTimeSelector.VNClockViewController' (0x1008122d0).`

Please tell me if you need to see more code.

EDIT: 
I'm using my fork of the Pods from github. 
Please use this pod in a sample project to see the error.

```
pod 'WWCalendarTimeSelector', :git => 'https://github.com/binsnoel/WWCalendarTimeSelector.git'
```

Try to instantiate VNClockViewController.instantiate() and see the error.

Comment: did you solved the issue ?\

Comment: no, i ended up not using the pod, and importing it directly on to the project. :/ @Androidteem

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same issue with same error, It's happening because of bug in Library

Steps to solve the issue

1) First goto `Pod -> WWCalendarTimeSelector -> Resource` folder

2) Select `WWCalendarTimeSelector.storyboard` and check in View hierarchy and Select Clock View as in image.

[image]

3) Now, got to `Identity Inspector` and You see `Custom class` have missing `Module`. So set `WWCalendarTimeSelector` as like below image

[image]

4) Done, Check and run.

Comment: Hi, what i'm trying to do is edit the Pods so I can have only the WWClock. So I added new files VNClockViewController and a new storyboard file VNClockViewController.storyboard containing only the WWClock. I tried to instantiate it the way the pod does in WWCalendarTimeSelector.instantiate() but I can't replicate it. It generates an error.

Comment: Hi,
i am facing following issue when i try to add it manually in objective c project.
No known class method for selector 'instantiate' ,  any suggestion?
thanks in advance

Comment: you soled this issue?